# Most compatible method for reading a file line-by-line in reverse

Tags: shell, readfile

Okay, so I have a script that generates a list of values (separated by newlines for simplicity) however they're generated and stored to file in one order, but I need to then process the file in the reverse order (I can't change how the first step operates for efficiency reasons as the dataset can get quite large).

I'm familiar with the useful commands `tac` and `tail -r` in bash, but unfortunately the environment I'm working within has neither (I don't believe it has much at all in addition to the main POSIX standard).

So what I'm looking for is the best way to read lines from a file in reverse-order, preferably with as little memory overhead as possible, as the file may grow to be quite large (though individual lines should be relatively small).

Comment: Your two goals seem to conflict: every time the file is appended to, it adds a record that you should have already consumed. Also, what is your environment?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [unix: How can I print lines from file backwards (without using “tac”)?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9356/how-can-i-print-lines-from-file-backwards-without-using-tac)

Comment: @chepner the first time I read the data I'm reading from a stream and processing the values to filter out only the ones I need, which I'm writing to a file. However to keep memory use sane for huge datasets I have to write the values out in the order I process them. But once that's done I need to then actually act upon them in the reverse order, so reading the file line-by-line in reverse is necessary. Currently I'm reading only chunks into memory for processing in reverse, but it's not pretty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method uses `sort` which will have a high memory overhead

```
cat -n filename | sort -rn | cut -f2-
```

If you have perl installed, you could use a module like [File::ReadBackwards](http://search.cpan.org/~uri/File-ReadBackwards-1.05/ReadBackwards.pm).

Comment: I'd hoped to avoid too much memory overhead, but the script is supposed to be portable so I can't rely on perl or bundling anything. Seems `sort` is the only real option then, thanks for the answer!